# summernote + PHP Mailer

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer, summernote

I tried using [summernote](https://gist.github.com/soomtong/6635053)

and PHP Mailer to sent the contents to my e-mail.

But the e-mail does not appear to be in HTML form eventhough I put :

```
$mail->IsHTML(true); //set email format to HTML
```

Below is my code for sending e-mail:

```
require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP(); //set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "mail.xxxyy.com"; //specify SMTP mail server
$mail->Port = "2525"; //specify SMTP Port
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; //turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "xxxxx@xxxxx.com"; //Full SMTP username
$mail->Password = "xxxxx"; //SMTP password

$mail->From = "xxxxx@xxx.com";
$mail->FromName = "xxxxx";
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxx", "Mei Yi");

$mail->WordWrap = 50; //optional, you can delete this line
$mail->IsHTML(true); //set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = "RE:". $_POST[txtFeedbackSubject2];

$mail->Body = htmlspecialchars($_POST['content']);

if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Message could not be sent.

";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
```

The e-mail content appears to be like this:

```
<span style=\"font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; text-decoration: underline;\">Aadadssdasadsad.</span>
```

Please advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be your magic quotes are enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You're applying `htmlspecialchars` to the body, which will prevent the HTML from being rendered. Don't do that.

Apart from that, your message body will be whatever is in `$_POST['content']`, over which PHPMailer has no control.

Comment: Hi. If I remove htmlspecialchars, my sentences would not get bolded. How do I ensure that my e-mail recieve the sentences from summernote text area as bolded?

Comment: Why do you say that? Applying htmlspecialchars will break all html formatting, effectively turning it into plain text. Is there some kind of double-encoding going on?